# Comparing files in two different directories

Tags: bash

In the bash script below, I am trying to compare the files of two folders. A file in folder `f1` will be deleted if it exists in folder `f2`.

```
#!bin/bash

for i in  `dir f1/*`
do
     for j in `dir f2/*`
     do
          if [[ $i = $j ]]
          then
                   `rm -fr f1/$i`
          else
          fi
    done
done
```

Ive also tried:

```
#!bin/bash

for i in  f1/*
do
     for j in f2/*
     do
          if [[ $i = $j ]]
          then
                   rm -fr f1/$i
          else
          fi
    done
done
```

But both give me `syntax error near unexpected token 'fi'`.

Am I right in my use/lack of backticks or brackets?

Comment: bash seems not to permit empty `else` clause. delete it.

Comment: The globs in the second are much better than the parsing of a command's output, just for the record. Do you care about the contents of the files at all or just the names?

Comment: @ymonad Thanks, that fixed the error. Unfortunately bash script isn't working though. @ Etan Reisner I just care about matching filenames. I'm assuming an equivalent name means equivalent file contents.

Comment: That's not at all a generally safe assumption but sure. See my answer.

Comment: Note that `$i` will never equal `$j` unless `f1` and `f2` are in fact misspelled in the question and actuall have the same value in your real script.  You should probably be looping over all the files in `f1` and then checking whether the file with the same basename exists in `f2` (a linear operation instead of a quadratic operation).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This script loops over the contents of `f2` once for each file in `f1`(which is going to be quite inefficient for large `f1` directories).

You can almost certainly do this in a much simpler fashion using something like `rsync` or simply a glob to `rm`.

That being said there's also no reason to test for filename equivalence at all (and especially so when using `rm -f`). You don't need to test for filename equivalence if all you want to do is access a file by name since you already know the name you care about from your outer loop. Additionally, you don't even need an existence test if you are removing a file with `rm -f` because `rm -f` does not fail, even when given a file that does not exist.

That being said there's no reason to loop over `f1` at all. Just loop over `f2` and delete (with `rm -f`, no need for `-r` unless you expect to delete directories) any files that have the same basename in `f1` as were in `f2`:

```
for file in f2/*; do
    rm -f f1/"$(basename "$file")"
done
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. That is indeed much simpler. I'm not sure why you say there's no need to test for filename equivalence when using `rm -f` though. Also, in the code `rm -f f2/...` should be changed to `rm -f f1/....` just so no one is caught unaware...

Comment: Indeed. Sorry for the directory confusion. Fixed. And yes, that comment was poorly explained. I've edited it to, hopefully, explain better.